# How to create a minimap to show all content of div in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, canvas

How to create a minimap to show all content of `<div id="{{ innerDivId }}">` in `<div id="minimap">`?

```
<div id="powerSystemDiagram">
    <div id="{{ innerDivId }}">
        // Content
    </div>
    <div id="minimap">
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't use html2svg because it does not support typescript.
So I've used html2canvas or converted it to SVG and appended it into minimap. However, both ways give a part of the content (which is visible on the screen) because the content is too long (height about 20.000px).

First way: convert to SVG

```
public createMinimap(): void {
        const container = document.getElementById(this.innerDivId);
        const minimapContent = document.querySelector('.minimap');
        if (minimapContent && container) {
            const svgRect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
            svgRect.setAttribute('width', container.offsetWidth.toString());
            svgRect.setAttribute('height', container.offsetHeight.toString());
            svgRect.setAttribute('fill', container.style.backgroundColor);
            minimapContent.appendChild(svgRect);
        }
}
```

Second way: use html2canvas

```
public createMinimap(): void {
        const container = document.getElementById(this.innerDivId);
        const minimapContent = document.querySelector('.minimap');
        if (container && minimapContent) {
            const totalContentHeight = Array.from(container.children).reduce((totalHeight, child) => totalHeight + child.clientHeight, 0);
            const originalHeight = container.style.height;
            container.style.height = `${totalContentHeight}px`;
            // Capture the entire content using html2canvas
            void html2canvas(container).then((canvas) => {
                minimapContent.innerHTML = '';
                minimapContent.appendChild(canvas);
                container.style.height = originalHeight;
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need an SVG or Canvas converter? You can use `cloneNode` to copy the whole `div` including all contents. Then place the copy in its proper container, and then use `transform` to make it really small.

```
let minimap = target.cloneNode(true)
containter.appendChild(minimap)
minimap.classList.add("minimap")
```

and in css

```
.minimap {
     transform: scale(0.1);
}
```